# avocado leaf getting black spots near vein

Tags: diseases, leaves, avocado, discoloration

~1.5 year old indoor avocado plant recently started getting these black spots near the central vein. It's only on the top face of the leaf and only one leaf is affected.

There seems to be no difference in texture on the leaf. besides this spotting the plant is general of ok health.

as seen in the image below, the spotting is only visible on the bottom when light shines through the leaf.

I couldn't find any images of this sort of spotting online so if you have any idea what this might be I'd appreciate it.

[image: 4 close-up photos of avocado leaf with black spots near vein. top 2 images are of the top and bottom of the leaf in direct sunlight and two bottom photos are of the top and bottom of leaf in indirect sunlight]

Answer (score 2):

Does not look like insect pests and does look more like a virus/fungus/bacteria that has taken advantage of soil conditions to find a new home.

Diagnostics:

- only happens on older leaves
- cannot be removed from the leaf with a fingernail  (I.e.: is inside the leaf)

Potential solutions:

- change watering regime: are you overwatering?
- move to increase light levels
- repot in new soil less mix

Most houseplants are over watered. Avocados are trees that do not adapt well to being kept smaller.  A vigorous plant will convert the organic matter in the pot into avocado stuff which can create a mix that compacts over time and creates an anerobic environment in the soil which is great for fungus/virus/bacteria to find a home.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what they are. My best guess is a minute sap sucking creature.

I found them on my year old avocado where they caused patches of paling of the leaf.

I found I could scrub them of with a soft/non-scratch pot scourer. Support the leaf with one hand and gently rub the top surface of the leaf with a wet scrub pad. The result is a brown pad that rinses out well.